# Vertical alignment of components of jpanels using GridLayout

Tags: java, swing, grid-layout

I am making KenKen as my term project using java swing library. For alignment I have used gridbag and gridlayout, But now i want to add one more component of JPanel to the UI. These screenshots will make the problem more clear:

[image: Before I click on the button in the lowest panel below]

Now I select the grid cell to which i want to add respective candidates of in the left most panel.

[image: This is what happens when I click the number buttons 2, 3, 4]

It disturbs the adjacent alignments of the grid and panels.

Here are the panels with their respective layouts:

```
 JPanel buttonPanel = new JPanel();
 buttonPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 4, 5, 5));
 buttonPanel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(20,40));
 buttonPanel.add(undoButton);
 buttonPanel.add(redoButton);
 buttonPanel.add(eraseButton);
 buttonPanel.add(hintButton);

 JPanel cellPanel = new JPanel();
 cellPanel.setName("cellPanel");
 cellPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(pSize, pSize, 0, 0));

 JPanel numPanel = new JPanel();
 numPanel.setName("numPanel");
 numPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,1,5,5));
 numPanel.setPreferredSize((new Dimension(50,60)));

 JPanel candPanel = new JPanel();
 candPanel.setName("candidatesPanel");
 JLabel candidates = new JLabel("Candidates");
 candidates.setFont(new Font("Courier New", Font.ITALIC, 14));
 candidates.setForeground(Color.GRAY);
 candPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(0,1));
 candPanel.add(candidates);
```

Then it all goes into the content panel:

```
 content.add(buttonPanel, pos.nextCol().expandW());
 content.add(candPanel, pos.nextRow());
 content.add(new Gap(GAP) , pos.nextRow());  // Add a gap below
 content.add(cellPanel, pos.nextCol());
 content.add(numPanel,pos.nextCol().expandW());
```

The buttons are all generated on runtime, and they are added to the candPanel in an action listener.

Comment: *"I will share the code in the next post."*  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) (as an edit to **this** post).  BTW - never heard of 'crop'?  Alt-Print Screen crops a screenshot to just the active GUI.  See [How do I create screenshots?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99734/how-do-i-create-a-screenshot-to-illustrate-a-post) (for tips on making *great* screenshots).

Comment: I don't know why you replied to me to tell me of your edit.  I'm still waiting for an ***SSCCE.***

Comment: More people will be willing to help if you provide complete source code to help with debugging and better understanding of the situation.

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using a GridBagConstraints subclass of which I am unaware (variable `pos`), though I can guess its function from context.

Assuming your problem is that you want the `candidates` panel to be to the left of the `cellPanel`, and not above it, you need to swap the lines which add the `candPanel` and the `new Gap(GAP)` as follows:

```
content.add(buttonPanel, pos.nextCol().expandW());
content.add(new Gap(GAP), pos.nextRow());   // These two lines
content.add(candPanel, pos.nextRow());      // swapped over
content.add(cellPanel, pos.nextCol());
content.add(numPanel,pos.nextCol().expandW());
```